# Ignoring suite names to run from the command line

Tags: protractor

When specifying suites to run from the command line, is it possible to provide suite names to ignore?

I'm sure I saw somewhere, perhaps in another issue here that you could use a `!` prefix on a suite name when setting the `--suites` parameter value, but I cant recall where I did see this, maybe I dreamt it?!

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear for me. Let's take a look at common case.
What should be at your config file:

```
suites: {
  homepage: 'tests/e2e/homepage/**/*Spec.js',
  search: [
    'tests/e2e/contact_search/**/*Spec.js',
    'tests/e2e/venue_search/**/*Spec.js'
  ] 
},
```

or like this:

```
suites: {
  smoke: 'tests/e2e/smoke/*.js',
  performance: 'tests/e2e/performance/*.js'
},
```

take a look how to use it in a console:

```
protractor config.js --suite smoke,performance
```

and if you want to run just one:

```
protractor config.js --suite performance
```